# Allow app to request authefication

Tags: macos, permissions, file-permissions, finder, authentication

I use [ForkLift](http://www.binarynights.com/) as default file manager. From time to time some files could be overwritten only with user permission. Finder asks password but Forklift just says that it is impossible.

[image]

Launching Forklift from terminal with sudo access does not help.

Comment: *"with sudo access does not help"* How are you attempting this?

Comment: @grgarside through terminal: `sudo open /Apps/ForkLift.app`

Comment: That doesn't run the app as sudo — see [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/119218/37797): you need to run the binary as sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the app binary as sudo for it to be run under sudo. Running the app package as sudo won't launch the app as sudo.

```
sudo /Applications/App.app/Contents/MacOS/App
```